# Firebase Deploy complete but website not shown

Tags: angular, firebase, deployment, firebase-hosting

it's my first time using Firebase. I deployed my angular project with the Firebase CLI, but when i navigate to the specified domain, i only see

> Welcome
>   Firebase Hosting Setup Complete
>   You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting.
>   Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

Here's my process to deploy:

```
firebase login
  ✔  Success! Logged in as [...]
firebase init
  select Hosting, select project, chose 'dist' as public dir
  ✔  Firebase initialization complete!
ng build --prod
firebase deploy
  ✔  Deploy complete!
```

This is now over 60 minutes ago, and i can't figure out why it's not online. Is 60 minutes not enough time for firebase? Can anyone share his experience or give me a hint what could be the reason why it's not online?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check your `dist` folder. After your build, is there an `index.html` in the dist root or is it in another subfolder like `dist/your-project-name/index.html`?

Comment: there are two things in the `dist`-directory: `index.html` and `my-project-name`-folder. The `my-project-name`-folder also has an `index.html` inside, so i tried specifying `dist/my-project-name/` as public directory, but still the same problem

Comment: i don't exactly know what i did wrong the first time, but after trying it again it works. when i find out what the problem was on my first try, i'll post it. thank you Mr Martens

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by following below steps:

1. Do `firebase init` step properly by giving correct inputs.

   During `firebase init` when it asked `What do you want to use as
   your public directory?public`

   As I have given `public` as a answer

   Make sure you give proper link.
2. run `firebase deploy` again. It should work.

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

Just a bit more of detail. As you are using Angular, after you build your App to production, it creates (normally) a /dist/ProjectName folder where it puts your files.
NOTE: if you want to change this, please refer to the option --outputPath on https://angular.io/cli/build

Sometimes (as newbies) we miss the right folder when asked on the firebase.init command...

No worries, it writes those settings at firebase.json, just open it and look for:

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/ProjectName",
```

Now change it to the desired path and there you go ;) Now you can repeat the firebase.deploy and it should all work.

Hope it helps

No it doesn't help because people don't use visual studio code, they use android studio like it was intended. There are no ng commands and there is certainly no dist

Answer (score 1):

Solution for flutter web dev

In the firebase.json file, provide web build path: `"public": "build/web"`.

```
hosting: {
  "public": "build/web",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After running `firebase init` you can rebuild your app by running `ng build` then run `firebase deploy` to deploy your app to firebse, it again shows welcome screen but wait for ***10 to 20 minutes*** because server is setting up the app and take some time to up and running the app then open app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I realized that I had the two index.html positions within the dist folder, as @Tim Martens suggested in the question commentary.

Then, in the firebase.json file, I changed:

```
"public": "dist/name-of-my-project",
```

...and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 firebase deploy
```

use

```
 firebase deploy --only hosting
```

Answer (score 0):

If deploy is completed but page not found then

go into dist folder like :"cd dist" and firebase deploy

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

{

```
"hosting": {
"public": "dist",
"ignore": [
"firebase.json",
"**/.*",
"**/node_modules/**"]
```

}

your firebase json can be like above. Then change it like below.

```
{
“hosting”: {
“public”: “dist/your_app_name”,
“ignore”: [
“firebase.json”,
“**/.*”,
“**/node_modules/**”
],}
```

and then try firebase deploy

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my web page in Visual Studio, what was giving me this error was that I didn't have a file called 'index.html', after renaming my file to index.html, I ran Deploy again and it worked.